# Backend fatal error when making a invoice

Tags: magento2, fatal-error, create-invoice

Now that the web store is almost ready, I am investigating how the processing of orders goes.

When I go to sales - orders - promotion - view, I come to the order.
Then I go to invoice (at the top of the screen) scroll down, and click on invoice entry.

Then I get an error message:

```
[Mon Apr 15 19:24:54.184279 2019] [lsapi:error] [pid 810902:tid 140179756345088] [client 185.217.171.22:56800] [host www.orionyx.org] 
Backend fatal error: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Return value of Magento\\InventorySourceSelection\\Model\\Request\\InventoryRequest::getItems() must be of the type array, null returned in /home/u36619p31939/domains/orionyx.org/public_html/vendor/magento/module-inventory-source-selection/Model/Request/InventoryRequest.php:102
Stack trace:
#0 /home/u36619p31939/domains/orionyx.org/public_html/vendor/magento/module-inventory-source-selection-api/Model/Algorithms/Result/GetDefaultSortedSourcesResult.php(110): Magento\\InventorySourceSelection\\Model\\Request\\InventoryRequest->getItems()
#1 /home/u36619p31939/domains/orionyx.org/public_html/vendor/magento/module-inventory-source-selection/Model/Algorithms/PriorityBasedAlgorithm.php(73): Magento\\InventorySourceSelectionApi\\Model\\Algorithms\\Result\\GetDefaultSortedSourcesResult->execute(Object(Magento\\InventorySourceSelection\\Model\\Request\\InventoryRequest), Array)
#2 /home/u36619p31939/domains/orionyx.org/public_html/vendor/magento/module-inventory-source-selection-api/Model/SourceSelectionService.php in /home/u36619p31939/domains/orionyx.org/public_html/vendor/magento/module-inventory-source-selection/Model/Request/InventoryRequest.php on line 102,
referer: https://www.orionyx.org/admin/sales/order_invoice/new/order_id/2/key/8fb69961f679934e4fe53733a11bb9c0e44c5288a860475eb8d7f43e7d067442/
```

I don't understand this at all.

Can someone explain to me what happened here and how I could solve this?

Sincerely!

Comment: I have since discovered that if I sell a standard product, the invoicing will go well.

When I sell a bundle product, it goes wrong! That is quite inconvenient, because the majority are bundle products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this problem by changing the contents of the 'bundle price type' and 'bundle sku type' tables from 'fixed' to 'dynamic'.

Comment: Can you add more details to this solution? I am facing the exact issue